# I am not able to get id through ajax from view to controller.but id is showing in alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is view page code and I want to send id through this Ajax code but   id is not posting in controller.I want to do question replacement one after another fetching from database.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {

   $("#next").click(function()
    {
       var qid=$("#q").val();
        alert(qid);
        var d1=$("#r1").val();
        var d2=$("#r2").val();
        var d3=$("#r3").val();
        var d4=$("#r4").val();
        $.ajax({url:"<?php echo base_url().'index.php/ajax/question1';?>",data:{id:qid,a1:d1,a2:d2,a3:d3,a4:d4},success:function(data)
                 { 
                   $("#dd").html(data);
                  }
              });
     });
   });
```

HTML code:

```
 <div id="dd">
  <input type="text" name="ans" id="q" value="<?php echo $row->id?>">
  Question:<label id="l1"><?php echo $row->q;?></label><br />
   A:<input type="radio" id="r1" name="r" value="<?php echo $row->op1;?>"/><?php echo $row->op1;?><br /> 
   B:<input type="radio" id="r2" name="r" value="<?php echo $row->op2;?> "/><?php echo $row->op2;?><br />
   C:<input type="radio" id="r3" name="r" value="<?php echo $row->op3;?>" /><?php echo $row->op3;?><br /> 
   D:<input type="radio" id="r4" name="r" value="<?php echo $row->op4;?>" /><?php echo $row->op4;?> <br />  
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="next" value="Save and Next">
```

Here is Controller code

```
 class ajax extends CI_Controller 

   {
     public function question()
    {
    $this->load->model('model');
    $r['row']=$this->model->qmodel();
    if($r)
     {

          $this->load->view('q',$r);
          }
  }

      public function question1()

       {

        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $a1=$this->input->post('a1');
        $a2=$this->input->post('a2');
        $a3=$this->input->post('a3');
        $a4=$this->input->post('a4');
        $ta=$this->input->post('ta');
        $e=$id+1;echo $id;
        echo $e;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Does the AJAX request return the right information if you inspect the responses in the Developer tools in the browser? Do you get any errors? Please find out at least if the problem is in the server side code, or in the processing of the response.

Comment: As per [`docs`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you don't specify request method default method of ajax is `GET` and in your controller your are accessing parameter using `POST` method

Comment: Thanks @M Khalid Junaid.it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

As per [`docs`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you don't specify request method default method of ajax is `GET` and in your controller your are accessing parameter using `POST` method

```
$.ajax({ type:'post' , url:'url '...
```